# Minimum element in empty array

Tags: c++, algorithm

If you have a function `int getMin(int a[], int n)` then what would you say is the cleanest solution to deal with the empty array case?

Comment: I'd probably use `std::min_element()` instead of writing my own. I think it returns the end iterator on an empty container.

Comment: Don't use `int` for `n`, use the appropriate integer: `size_t`.

Comment: there is no integer that is the minimum of an empty array of integers so the given return type is wrong. If you must keep the return type then you might throw an exception for this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Return a pointer to the minimum element instead of the element itself. This way, a pointer value of one past the end of the array can indicate not found. (Or in this case empty)

This is the strategy taken by `std::min_element`, which already implements what you're doing.

You can even implement this in terms of `std::min_element`:

```
int* getMin(int a[], int n)
{
    return std::min_element(a, a+n);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're looking for the minimum value in the array how about:

```
if (!n)
  throw YourPreferredException();
```

Or:

```
#include <limits>
//...
if (!n)
  return std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

Or, if it should never happen:

```
#include <cassert>
//...
assert(n);
```

It depends on the application and the values you're expecting to be passing in. What makes most sense and what fits the existing code base is hard to guess.

Comment: Might as well make that `if (!a || !n)`, too. @cnicutar: Because 0 is a valid return value. Why return a valid thing with invalid arguments?

Comment: 0 might be a legitimate value - if the range of the `int` array was -10 to 10 then it would be indistinguishable.

Comment: `if (n <= 0)`. or an `assert(n > 0)`, if you do thorough testing.

Comment: @Pubby8 - I've not really had much trouble with it, especially for integers representing a size. Clearly it's appropriate to stick to local coding styles regardless of the path taken though. If I *was* going to write it explicitly I'd do `(0 == n)` instead of `(n == 0)` though.

Comment: @yi_H - good point, I'm not usually in the habit of using signed types to store lengths of arrays :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe instead, do it the way the standard library does: Take two iterators as parameters and return the `end` parameter if the sequence is empty. Better still use `min_element` instead of rolling your own.

If you *need* to do it the array/length way either `throw` or return `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`

Comment: If you return min and do `min(x, getMin(a,0))`, the `getMin` call will "poison" the result. It's probably "more neutral" to return max instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely no "cleanest solution" absent an understanding of the domain. Mathematically, the infimum of any set of values from a domain is the greatest lower bound (in the domain) of all elements of the set. For the extended integers, this would be +infinity for an empty set. (See, e.g., the [Wikipedia article on Empty Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set#Extended_real_numbers)) If your domain is all C++ int values, a (mathematically consistent) return value would then be INT_MAX.